# Is the Public Records Act of 1993 in force?

Tags: india, legal-research, public-records

Jurisdiction: India

Legislation/Statute/... The Public Records Act, 1993

Merely what the title states. I don't see anything mentioning explicitly whether it is the case. Is The Public Records Act, 1993 still in force? Has it been superseded/repealed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find any record of it being superceded or repealed, so it appears to in force from the date shown at [section 1](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/show-data?actid=AC_CEN_27_37_00007_199369_1517807323041&sectionId=3084&sectionno=1&orderno=1):

> (1) This Act may be called the Public Records Act, 1993.
>
> (2) It shall come into force on such date<sup>1</sup> as the Central Government may, by notification in the Official Gazette, appoint
>
> ---
>
> <sub><sup>1</sup>1st March, 1995, vide notification No. S.O. 128(E), dated 1st March, 1995, see Gazette of India, Extraordinary, Part II, sec. 3(ii)</sub>
>
> ---

For completeness, the [Gazette of India](https://egazette.nic.in/(S(n2stz5iht1eabrsgaujniyko))/SearchNotificationDate.aspx?id=77124) is searchable, but my reading of Hindi is not good enough to assist further.